# mp4 media file opens as text document

Tags: video, quicktime, mp4

I've downloaded a video which is being shown as a document file in finder. When clicked on, it opens with TextEdit instead of QuickTime player.

[image: screenshot]

When I run the following command in terminal,

`file vid`

the output is "vid: ISO Media, MP4 Base Media v1 [IS0 14496-12:2003]."

I have other mp4 videos which give the same output as above but open normally with QuickTime Player.

How do I convert the document file to a playable mp4 file?

Comment: Can you open the "Get Info" window and set the default application to QuickTime?

Comment: What is the extension of this file, if it has one?

Comment: @nohillside Seems like QuickTime is not able to play the file. "The document “vid” could not be opened. QuickTime Player cannot open files in the “data” format."

Comment: @Jean_JD It doesn't have a file extension in its name. However it's file type is mp4 like I've mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the window that you show, you choice Other then select "All Applications"  then Quick Time and you tick the box "Always open with".

After your vid file will be always open with the program you choice above.

**Edit:**
You can also add the .mp4 extension to you the file name.

Comment: When I follow these steps, there's a popup "The document “vid” could not be opened. QuickTime Player cannot open files in the “data” format."

Comment: I tried the same thing, but with VLC media player, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: You can try by adding the .mp4 extension.

Comment: Yes, that works. Adding the .mp4 extension is the right solution - Its being recognised as a video and now opens normally.

Comment: Ok. I add this to my response. :-)